# How to lose fat on inner, upper thighs?

Tags: running

I exercise 6 times a week, ab/leg/arm workouts containing resistance and some weights (I don't think my problem is due to weights since they aren't that heavy) 3 days a week, 2 short sprint runs, 2 fartlek runs, a long cardio run 4-7 miles, occasionally switching it up doing a cardio workouy. The rest of my body is extremely tone being abs, toned arms/thighs/legs, but the upper, inner part of my thigh doesn't have a 'thigh gap', how do I achieve this (not to be anorexic but I feel like I should have or try to get one due to all of my training). My inner/upper thighs do have 'muscle' there but is covered by 'fat', but not cellulite. My diet is okay, I eat a 5-a-day but also do have treats, but definitely don't overeat at all (I'm teenage female). I've been told reducing fat/toning upper thighs cannot be done through spot reducing so can my problem be resolved due to walking a lot more? Thanks.

Comment: Thigh gaps are unnatural and potentially damaging. You're better off increasing the amount of muscle you have right now. I would replace some of your cardio with more weight training and actually using weights that *are* heavy (to you).

Answer (score 1):

The gap is achieved by way of fat loss, and also by building a certain amount of muscles (by squatting) which will help tighten up the skin around your upper thigh.

And as you've already been told, let me just confirm it; no, you cannot pick and choose where you wish to reduce fat. You gain and lose fat all over, based on caloric surplus/deficit.